# How to programmatically add reverb effect to sound files in Java?

Tags: java, signal-processing, playback, javasound

I want to add a reverb effect for audio files in Java or at the very least the playback of those audio files. The Java program is a desktop application so I cannot use the android libraries. I have tried use the controls on the ports using the Java Sound API, but it has not worked on my test machine. (My tests show that none of the ports support reverb control).

```
        Port line = null; 
    if (AudioSystem.isLineSupported(Port.Info.SPEAKER)) {
        try {
            line = (Port) AudioSystem.getLine(
                Port.Info.SPEAKER);
        }
        catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }
    }
    EnumControl reverb = (EnumControl)line.getControl(EnumControl.Type.REVERB);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(reverb.getValues()));
```

The above code has not worked. Is there a way I can manually add a reverb effect? Perhaps through some overlooked api or by manipulating the waveform and or playback of that waveform? Any advice at all would be duely appreciated.

Comment: I see you _getting_ the reverb control value. I don't see you doing anything to actually turn on reverb...

Comment: None of the devices on my computer support reverb control... It throws an error stating that Reverb control is not supported on this line. After checking every port on my system I discovered that reverb control is not supported on any of my ports.

Comment: It's a big job. I've done echo (for a Theremin applet) but I can't explain it here without writing a full-blown tutorial. The Java Tutorials has two sort of helpful parts: a small section on Controls at the end (says you can do it yourself--gee thanks), and a code example for reading a file in the "Formats" tutorial that follows the "Controls" tute, where it shows you where you can hook in. You'll have to learn about formats and converting bytes to DSP and back. Echo is not so bad but Reverb is over my head, involves understanding about filtering, convolution, much more.

Comment: Would you please post a tutorial on echo at the very least? It would be greatly appreciated. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your drivers don't support reverb, but do support playing back multiple sounds overlapping each other, you could play back the same sound several times with a short delay between instances and decreasing volume each time. "Proper" reverb would also do a bit of filtering on each repetition, but this should be close enough.

If your drivers don't let you do it that way, you could try reprocessing the sound itself to add reverb before playing it, using the same approach.

Comment: My question would is how to implement either of these techniques.

Comment: http://www.amazon.com/dp/0130876763/?tag=googhydr-20&hvadid=43825612169&hvpos=1t1&hvexid=&hvnetw=g&hvrand=15028765801108904978&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=e&hvdev=t&ref=pd_sl_1qzw1dg4ix_e is a bit dated but covers this.